# Can structures in mathematical structuralism be models also?

Tags: philosophy-of-mathematics

This is a question about structures as defined by structuralism in philosophy of mathematics.

From this [article](https://iep.utm.edu/m-struct/), it uses the term "system" which is usually (not by structuralists) denoted as "structure", or simply "model", while it reserves the term "structure" to denote what is common to all similar systems, which is thought of a kind of a universal exemplified exclusively by all those systems.

To clarify, what mathematical-logicians commonly call as structures , the structuralists call as *systems*,
they propose the existence of a kind of a universal (for a full understanding of this term see [here](https://iep.utm.edu/universa/)) that is shared by all and only those systems, and they call that universal as "structure".

This is a quote from the above referenced article:

> A structure is thus a “one over many,” a sort of universal.  The difference between a structure and a more traditional universal, such as a property, is that a property applies to, or holds of, individual objects, while a structure applies to, or holds of, systems.  Structures are thus much like structural universals, whose existence remains subject to debate among metaphysicians (see, for example, Lewis [1986], Armstrong [1986], Pagès [2002])).  Indeed, one might think of a mathematical structure as a sort of free-standing structural universal, one in which the nature of the individual objects that fill the places of the structure, is irrelevant (see Shapiro [2008, §4]).

So to reconcile that with common terminology used in mathematical logic, one can restate the definition of a structure (as meant by structuralism) as:

A structure is a universal that is exclusively exemplified by all models of some formal theory.

Note: this needs not be confused with the concept of set or class of all models. Here structuralists are speaking about a universal that all models of some theory satisfy and only those models satisfy, but they describe it having places which are freely filled by any object (what they call as free-standing) and seeminly bonds also between those places, in a way that parallel relations in the relational systems exemplifying them, such a description makes one wonder if structuralists do think of what they call as structure (i.e. a free-standing structural universal) to also constitute a model of the underlying theory?

> Now, my question here, is: would the stucture (according to structuralism when perceived as a [structural universal](https://compass.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/full/10.1111/phc3.12518#:%7E:text=There%20are%20two%20kinds%20of,differing%20behavior%20of%20their%20instantiations)),  of models of a theory T, itself qualify as a model of that theory also?

Zuhair

Comment: "*would the stucture (according to structuralism) of models of a theory T itself qualify as a model of that theory also?*" Assuming I understand your question, consider an algebraic structure such as a group.  The (proper) class of all groups would not be a group though it may be possible to impose some structure upon it other than a group structure.

Comment: why you think a proper class qualify as a structural universal?

Comment: I didn't intend to say that the class of all groups is a structural universal.  The group axioms define the structural universal.

Comment: @nwr, so what's the relevance of your argument about the proper class of all groups?

Comment: What exactly is "the stucture (according to structuralism) of models of a theory T"? I don't see a precise definition of that. (I have no idea what "a universal that is exclusively exemplified by all models of some formal theory" means exactly.)

Comment: I was simply suggesting that whatever structure one may wish to impose upon the class of all groups, it is not a group structure.

Comment: @nwr, Ah I see. Thanks. So is it a particularity, I mean some structures may be models or to put it in structuralist terms some structures are themselves systems while in other cases they may not be?

Comment: @NoahSchweber, you need to read articles about structuralism and structural universals etc... It's helpful to remotely parallel this with the case of a property and individuals satisfying (exemplifying) that property, but here you just have it over systems (models) instead of individuals. Since a structural universal is a COMPLEX universal, then it appears to be also a kind of a system (model) that is examplified by other more concrete models? However, I'm not sure if the composition of  structural universal satisfy it being a system as well or even if it models the same underlying theory?

Comment: Your confusion might come from the almost synonymous usage of structure and model in mathematical logic... However, unlike in model theory, in philosophy of mathematical structuralism here, structure is a further step of conceptual abstraction than any semantic model ignoring any intrinsic nature of mathematical objects if there are such objects at all. Thus here it's not qualified exactly as a model of a theory...

Comment: @DoubleKnot, I didn't fully understand what you are saying, the language is not clear to me. In particular I don't know what you mean by: structure is a further step of conceptual abstraction than any semantic model ignoring any intrinsic nature of mathematical objects if there are such objects at all. In particular which is the subject of "ignoring" is it "strucure" or "semantic model"?

Comment: @DoubleKnot, by the way I already alluded to the terminology, I said what we commanly call structure (in mathemtical logic) it is called as "system" by structuralist, while structure (in structuralism) mean a universal ranging over all similar systems. My question would the strucutre (in structuralists terms) itself qualify of being a system also? I know that it ranges (exemplified by) all the similar systems, but my question can it include itself among the systems its ranging over?

Comment: Maybe useful [Structuralism in the Philosophy of Mathematics](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/structuralism-mathematics/): *structures* in math are... structures. We may assume that we know them in some way; when we "compare" them to some formal theory, we say that a certain structure is a *model* of the theory if axioms of the formal theory are true when interpreted in that structure.

Comment: IMO "system" is not technically defined; see SEP's entry: "As Benacerraf argued, there is something wrong with identifying “the natural numbers” with a particular set-theoretic system". Here the author means that into set theory we define a "collection" of sets whose properties satisfy the Peano's axiom (to be precise, more than one construction is possible). If so, one of those systems is not **the** structure, because the structure must be the "universal" common to all those constructions.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA, what the structuralists call "system" they most of the time mean what we call as structure or as model. The structuralist call them relational systems to mean a tuple of a set (domain) or even several domains, and relations on them, we usually call those as structures but they don't call them as such because they reserve the term 'structure' to denote something that all systems capturing some theory (i.e. all models) exclusively share. But the problem is that this something (the structure) is itself said to be constituted of parts related to each other

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA ... continuation, ... in a manner paralleling the systems (i.e. models) that exemplify them, this is called as a 'structural universal', but if a structure is a structural universal then it appears to me that the structure itself may qualify as a system that captures the underlying theory, i.e. a model of the underlying theory. Is that the case? That's the question.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA, the question is about how do we think structures themselves composed of, if we think that structures are simple universals, i.e. for example atoms, that is not composed of distinct proper parts, then of course a structure is not a model. But if we think of the structures themselves as a kind of what shapiro calls "Free-Standing Structural Universal", then I'd think matters would differ, and such kind of Complex universals might qualify to be themselves systems capturing the underlying theory, that is models!

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA, for structural universals see: https://compass.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/full/10.1111/phc3.12518#:~:text=There%20are%20two%20kinds%20of,differing%20behavior%20of%20their%20instantiations.

Comment: What I'm saying is if we view "Mathematical Structures" as kinds of "Structural universals", then impredicativity issues would be raised! That's the whole point of the question.

Comment: According to common English production rules, ignoring neither structure nor semantics, but the very (intrinsic) nature of any mathematical objects, if they exist at all. So only extrinsic structural relations are considered here…

Comment: For your 2nd part question, you should employ 2nd order logic then a structure is just a relational predicate, but only a predicate variable can range over its domain. So seems you’re confusing a particular structure and a structure variable… Things are clear to me here.

Comment: Yes but it need not be captured this way! You can take structure to be the image of a function that assigns structures to systems after isomorphism, this way a structure can itself be a system if its parts are to parallel the relations its capturing

Comment: Ok, so at least you agree my straightforward way of comprehension. As for your way described above if I understood correctly, a problem is the *image* of any function is a set of mathematical objects with intrinsic semantics that cannot be captured by structualism, thus cannot be isomorphed/identified as a relational predicate (structure per structualism of interest here). From set theory we can only identify a function as a dictionary object/map between domain and image. So you might again confuse a system (pure structure, relation) with its image (non-pure structure mixed with semantics)...

Comment: Yes, I agree that the higher type predicate logic you are alluding to will put structures at higher level than the pure relational systems exemplifying them, and thus even if a structure is conceived as a structural universal with parts paralleling the relational systems still this would place the structure at higher level than the pure relational systems, but the problem is that I see this in some sense artificial, a structural universal itself can be seen as a relational system of higher type and actually it ought to have a structure over it, which would be of higher type

Comment: continuation... which would itself qualify as a relational system of higher type which needs a higher strucutre and so on.... You are just shifting matters up at higher and higher abstraction levels. My point is that ALL these would still have a similar patters of relations, and so ought to be captured by a structure! My function strategy would keept matters at one level, so we can check whether a structure itself can be among the systems exemplifying it. To me this appears more fair, or lets say have more capacity to express matters.